# PSET 4 REFLECT error not reflecting last row

Tags: cs50

I am not sure what is happening. It reflects everything right except from the last pixel of each column which does not change at all. Please help me with this, thanks :)
The assignment is from cs50x.

```
// Reflect image horizontally

void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]){
    
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            int a = h;
            int b = w;
            
            image[a][b] = image[h][width - 1 - w];
            image[h][width - 1- w] = image[h][w];
            image[h][w] = image[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just creating another answer, I figured out the actual problem! You have to create a temporary array to store the RGB values. Here is the correct code:

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //Iterating over all pixels
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {

        for (int w = 0; w < width / 2; w++)
        {

            //Creating array to store pixel values
            int temppixel[3];

            temppixel[0] = image[h][w].rgbtRed;
            temppixel[1] = image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
            temppixel[2] = image[h][w].rgbtBlue;

            //Making the last pixel be equal the first
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtRed;
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtGreen;
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtBlue;

            //Now placing the first pixel in the last position; done reflecting
            image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtRed = temppixel[0];
            image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtGreen = temppixel[1];
            image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtBlue = temppixel[2];

        }

    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks, Nicolas!! It does work perfectly. I have a question, why did you create an array to store the values of each pixel?

Comment: You're welcome! This is necessary because if you don't have this temporary array to store the pixels, and you set (for example), the first pixel equal to the last, and then the last to the first, the last pixel will not change. We have to keep a temporary array of the RGB values in order to switch the first pixel with the last, or else if we simply assign one to the other, one of the values will be lost. Imagine this:
`a = b`
`b = a`
Then you will be assigning b to itself since `a` is `b`

In order to preserve `a` original value, you have to create a temporary variable, like this:

Comment: `temp = a`
`a = b`
`b = temp`
Does it make sense?

(P.S - Can you mark my new answer as 'correct' by clicking the checkmark, because if you don't, anyone else that has the same problem won't know the correct solution to this problem) Thank you! Hope you can succeed in CS50's course. (I'm also doing it, in week 6!!)

Comment: Yes! That makes a lot of sense. I actually changed my code before you sent the correct one and I cannot figure it out why it does not work!

Comment: Thre I attached my code, I know it is quite difficult to understand it due to the format but if you could take a look at it I would appreciate it a lot, thanks!

Comment: I have no idea how to write a code in the comments... I will figure it out

Comment: Ok!. Just to let you know how to do it in the comments. Just enclose your text with these: ` One before the code, and one after (for inline code, because it's what you can do in the comments)

Comment: Hey! the problem is is that you're creating a temporary address, not the actual value stored in it. You can use the code in my answer! Just copy and paste. If you have any questions feel free to ask me!